# Java: How to use pattern.matcher

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am trying to parse an html page using jsoup. I check the contentType of each element and want to print all elements which are not of type text/html. I am using pattern matching after getting the content type of the element. With the above code I see that elements of type text/html are getting printed

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url;
    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
    url = "https://www.google.com";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //parse the html code pointed by url
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            if(urlValidator.isValid(link.attr("href"))) { //check if the element is a url
                URL portfolio_url = new URL(link.attr("href"));
                URLConnection c = portfolio_url.openConnection();
                String link_type = c.getContentType();
                System.out.println(link_type);
                if(link_type != null) {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(link_type, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  // case-insensitive matching
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("text/html");
                    if(matcher.find() != true) {
                        System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, please ask in [mcve format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).. you can try using [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org) as a start for accessing the urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can to this using linux utilities  [Wget](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

```
wget -r www.mytargetsite.com
```

Then run below command which would reveal all urls,

```
 find www.mytargetsite.com
```

here's the sample output

```
$ wget -r www.blackorange.biz
$ find www.blackorange.biz/
www.blackorange.biz/
www.blackorange.biz/services.html
www.blackorange.biz/contact.html
www.blackorange.biz/images
www.blackorange.biz/images/projectimg1.jpg
```

note: this also downloads all pages for you